# css3 borders and box-shadow effects

Tags: css

I am not sure how but I want to make a border and with box-shadow add a second lighter layer to that border adding depth to the entire thing just like in this image.

[image]

Any suggestion as to how it can be done? Left border is what I want to achieve.

Comment: That looks like a border:2px inset (pick a blue);

Comment: what have you tried so far? how far have you got? What you're asking can be achieved using standard borders; doesn't need box shadows or anything like that.

Comment: This may help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style

Comment: @Spudley I haven't tried anything yet, I was thinking of using double box-shadow property on the div with the border making an illusion. But I actually did not know you can do that with pure CSS and border only, must have missed that. Would styled border work in cross-browser? FF, Chrome/Safari and Opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, using `box-shadow`:

```
body { background: #555; }
div {
    background: #666;
    border: 1px solid #393939;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #999;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2n2RE/

Then just adjust the color values as desired. You could also change the blur amount on the `box-shadow` to achieve different looks.